# Python IDLE: cmd-v to paste not working on OS X

Tags: python, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macports, python-idle

I am using Python 2.7.3 on OS X 10.8.3, installed with MacPorts. If I hit <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> on content in IDLE, I can paste it with <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> into other apps. However, I cannot use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste into IDLE itself, either from other apps or from within IDLE.

If I highlight content in IDLE, a right-click on the mouse will duplicate (i.e. paste) that content. This is sort of a workaround, but it is annoying not to be able to paste URL's or code from outside of IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the cursor more than one space after the last `>>>`. It won't paste unless you do.

Answer (score 0):

The cmd+C and cmd+V commands weren't working for me either, so I removed them (and macports) and then installed python from the python.org website. I only needed numpy and matplotlib, so I installed those from their sources and it works.

It isn't a solution, but the broken hotkeys seem to have something to do with x11 (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-January/563387.html). I installed XQuartz(http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) and it still didn't help, so I just removed everything.